# Changing WooCommerce membership status

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, status, woocommerce-memberships

I've been banging my head for about a week now. any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a WooCommerce store where I need to be able to update the user's membership status (canceled, active, etc) through Php.

I know I can grab their current status with:

```
wc_memberships_get_user_membership( $user_id, $membership_id );
```

and create new memberships with:

```
wc_memberships_create_user_membership( $args );
```

but I haven't found a way to just change the status.

thanks!

Comment: You want to change the status for all users? and immediately?

Comment: no, I need to change the status for one user on one membership

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so after searching around for more than a month, and going back and forth with Woocommerce's support team (they were no help :/ ), I came up with this solution:

Swimming around in the database I noticed that all memberships are just posts, and they have an ID and a post author. so I figured I could write up a little SQL to make it work.

using WordPres's built-in [$wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows) class I was able to just update the field directly in the database:

first you have to include $wpdb in your function:

```
            global $wpdb;
```

then you put the query together, below is what it looks like in regular SQL

```
        UPDATE ie_posts
        SET post_status ='wcm-active'
        WHERE post_parent = 49 AND post_author = 49870
```

And here's what is looks like using the class:

```
        $wpdb->update('ie_posts',
            array('post_status' => $_status),
            array('post_parent' => $_membership_id,
                  'post_author' => $_user_id)
        );
```

**I would advise trying this using a development copy of your database so you don't break anything.**

deff not the prettiest way of doing it, but it works like a charm. if anyone has a better way of taking care of it, please let me know.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else coming here. Here is my preferred solution.
A WooCommerce Membership is just another WordPress post in your database and the membership status is stored as the post status.
WooCommerce Memberships comes with the following statuses by default:

- Active
- Cancelled
- Complimentary
- Delayed
- Expired
- Paused
- Pending Cancellation

In the database the statuses above look like this:

- wcm-active
- wcm-cancelled
- wcm-complimentary
- wcm-delayed
- wcm-expired
- wcm-paused
- wcm-pending

All you need to do now is for example this:

```
$status = 'wcm-paused';
$update_args = array( 'ID' => $membership_id, 'post_status' => $status );
wp_update_post($update_args);
```

I hope this helps others.

P.s.: I always prefer using core functions over accessing the database directly. Unlike possible database changes, wp_update_post is a function that is fundamentally used in WordPress and will not disappear in the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try this way, for example to get any membership with a 'pending' status:

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

$args = array( 
    'status' => 'pending'
); 

$pending_memberships = wc_memberships_get_user_memberships( $user_id, $args );
```

Then and with a conditional check, you should be able to change this pending status to another one.

Comment: ok, cool. how do you go about changing it though? that's the part I'm stuck in. 
let's say a user has 2 memberships, and I need to modify the status of one.

Comment: I have the same problem, can't find command for modifying the status...any update?

Comment: @Stephen yes, see my answer. it's dirty, but it works

Answer (score 0):

Tested the following code with v1.17.1  (derived from `class-wc-memberships-user-memberships.php`)

```
$user_membership = wc_memberships_get_user_membership( $user_id, $membership_plan_id );
$user_membership->update_status( 'expired' );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking a way to allow user to get a free membership then upgrade to other membership then the below code help you with this.

When someone completes a purchase that includes a membership, the system checks if they already have an active membership. If they do, it automatically pauses the older membership and activates the new one once the order is completed. This ensures that our customers can upgrade or change their memberships seamlessly without any overlap or confusion. Additionally, when an order is initially processed, the system temporarily pauses the new membership until the order is fully completed, preventing any issues with multiple active memberships. It's a smooth way to make sure everything regarding memberships is handled neatly and efficiently, giving customers the best experience possible.

Hope this will help you if you are planning to allow user to assign the free membership once user register and if they want to upgrade to another membership then the below code will help you to achieve this.

Make sure you assign the free membership manually not in registration directly, if you want to allow the free membership registration then create a separate registration form for this. So for the paid memebrship once they click they should get redirect to checkout page and after successful purchase the membership will be assigned to them and you have to change the order status from processing to completed to make the membership active. :)

```
// Membership Switch - Old Membership will be paused once the new membership become active
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'handle_memberships_on_order_complete');

function handle_memberships_on_order_complete($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    if (!$order) return;

    $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
    if ($user_id <= 0) return;

    // Ensure the WooCommerce Memberships plugin is active
    if (!function_exists('wc_memberships_get_user_memberships') || !function_exists('wc_memberships_get_user_membership')) {
        return;
    }

    $memberships = wc_memberships_get_user_memberships($user_id, array('status' => 'active'));
    if (empty($memberships)) return;

    // Sort memberships by start date to identify the most recent
    usort($memberships, function($a, $b) {
        return strtotime($a->get_start_date('edit')) - strtotime($b->get_start_date('edit'));
    });

    $latest_membership = end($memberships); // Get the latest membership
    $latest_membership_id = $latest_membership ? $latest_membership->get_id() : null;

    foreach ($memberships as $membership) {
        // If an older active membership is found that is not the latest, pause it
        if ($membership->get_id() != $latest_membership_id) {
            $membership->update_status('wcm-paused');
        }
    }

    // Ensure the latest membership related to this order is set to active
    // Check if the latest membership is linked to the current order
    if ($latest_membership && $latest_membership->get_order_id() == $order_id) {
        $latest_membership->update_status('wcm-active');
    }
}



//As the woocommerce order first goes to processing to this will keep the new membership as a paused. Once the status is changes to complete this will pause the old membership and will
//make the new membership active
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'pause_memberships_for_processing_orders');

function pause_memberships_for_processing_orders($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    
    if (!$order) {
        return;
    }
    
    // Check if WooCommerce Memberships is active
    if (!function_exists('wc_memberships_get_user_memberships')) {
        return;
    }
    
    $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
    
    // Proceed only if there's a logged-in user associated with the order
    if ($user_id <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    
    $memberships = wc_memberships_get_user_memberships($user_id, array('status' => 'wcm-active'));
    
    foreach ($memberships as $membership) {
        // Check if the membership is linked to the order being processed
        $linked_order_id = $membership->get_order_id();
        
        if ($linked_order_id == $order_id) {
            // Check if the membership was just activated (you may need to refine this logic based on your setup)
            // Here we assume we're pausing all active memberships linked to this order
            $membership->update_status('wcm-paused');
        }
    }
}
```